# Hosting Recommendations For "CouchDB with an external agent" Model

Tags: node.js, hosting, couchdb

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305543/user-signup-in-couchapp-couchdb-through-jquery-couch-js-or-otherwise) I would like to have an external processes running that listens for new users, and then creates a user database.

I have a couch hosted on IrisCouch, and I would like to have a list of hosting services where one could host an external process that

1. Is free (at least free for low volume)
2. Can make long running connections to IrisCouch ( for long polling changes feed)
3. Is node.js
4. That one can feel comfortable putting the secure credentials of admin details for IrisCouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [nodester.com](http://nodester.com)